# How to make a custom keyboard shortcut WITH NO MODIFIER

Tags: keyboard

I just bought the super awesome app Sketch 2 and am loving it but I want to create a shortcut for a tool that currently has no shortcut assigned to it. Many other tools have a single letter shortcut (like the vector tool is just "V", no modifiers involved) but when I try to make a single character shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, it won't let me. It appears I have to provide a modifier and character :( Any way around this restriction?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)'s Device Key trigger:

> #### Device Key
>
> The macro can be executed when the key is pressed, released or periodically while it is held down. The trigger can also optionally be restricted to when certain modifier keys are pressed.

Device Key triggers can be combined with a macro group restricting to a certain application.

Comment: hmm. I'm sure that's a useful app but I'm not sure it's worth 36 dollars to not have to press a modifier key. At least in my case. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Once you buy Keyboard Maestro you keep on finding uses for it. I use it's power constantly.